# Weird apache session (?) issues

Tags: php, apache, session, locking

I encounter a weird problem i cannot resolve. My setup is as follows:

- 1 centos server running apache
- 1 mySql backend
- Running in the cloud

I got 1 pc, 2 laptops and 1 mobile (samsung s2) at home. When I browse to my website hosted on the apache server with my pc and 2 laptops at the same time everything works perfectly. But when I browse to the website with my mobile (wifi), I will get a timeout on my pc and 2 laptops:

This webpage is not available, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

After the website is loaded on my mobile everything on the pc and 2 laptops works fine. So everytime I use my mobile phone to browse the website I get an connection time out on my pc and laptops.

This problem also occurs on other networks. So it's not a problem with my home network/router configuration. At home i can only reproduce this problem with my mobile. Other people also reported this problem. The only link I have is that it always occurs when browsing on the same network.

What i tried to resolve this problem:

- Looked in the apache configuration
- Searched log files for clues
- Disabled iptables on the webserver

But i cannot find any related settings that might cause this problem. It seems like when i browse to the website with my mobile that all other connections comming from the same ip address are blocked. When the site is fully loaded on my mobile this block/lock disappears.

Does anyone have a clue where i should start looking?

P.s. I did not mention the website url on purpose.

Comment: Maybe something like "max number of concurrent connections". Maybe some Mobile browsers open to much simultaneous connections so there are none left for others.

Comment: But if that was the case then everyone should get the connection error. It only happens to people on the same network.